# Regex containing at least a character. Double quotes in pair. Should not contain @ and?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I need a custom regular expression for validating an input name field in HTML. The pattern should contain:

1. at least a letter
2. should not contain '@' and '?'
3. Double quotation marks must be used in pair
4. Spaces can only be used between double quotation marks
5. and the minimum length is 1.

Invalid Input String:

1. aaaaa@
2. 111111#
3. 111@
4. aaaaa?
5. aaa aaaa
6. aaaa"
7. @#1234

Valid Input String:

1. aaaa"aaa aaaa"
2. aaaaa
3. a11

I have written the regex for 1st and 2nd condition:

```
^((?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z]))[^?@]+$
```

I am not able to make a regex for 3rd and 4th condition

Comment: How is `as@` (your 4th condition) a valid input string when you say the `@` character shouldn’t appear in the string?

Comment: Yes two of them worked

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sure! Actually, I am new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the listed requirements (not matching `as@` because it contains an `@`) You might use:

```
^(?=[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z])(?:[^?@"\s]|"[^@?"\r\n]*")+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z])` Assert at least 1 time a-z or A-Z
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^?@"\s]` Match any char except `?`, `@`, `"` or a whitespace character
  - `|` Or
  - `"[^@?"\r\n]*"` Match an opening `"`, 0+ times any char except the listed and closing `"`
- `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n2mxte/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this .`(?=^.*[a-zA-Z].*$)(?=^[^@?]*$)(?=^[^" ]*("[^"]*")*[^" ]*$)^.*$`

[This is a demo.](https://regex101.com/r/O8yWWF/1)

`(?=^[^" ]*("[^"]*")*[^" ]*$)` This regex match "Double quotation marks must be used in pair  AND Spaces can only be used between double quotation marks"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `as@` must be true in your 5 roles. But this is matches with all valid input except`as@`:

```
^\w+(?:"[\w ]+")*$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMuwKy/1)